# Abort 404 not working in flask after request

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I have a multi domain website with flask but I want to restrict access to all views and blueprints except those I allowed access to them in some domains. So I decided to use flask after request decorator to do that but the problem is abort is not working in flask after request. What is the problem?

This is my sample code:

```
@app.after_request
def restricted_access(response):
    if g.site == 'store':
        return abort(404)
    return response
```

Comment: I think you can check externally, `print g.site` whether it yields the right value?

Comment: @Navaneethan Yes I can use that but I have some many views and I need something to use in all views like a after request to use it globally. also after request in not good either because at first the view function is processed.

Comment: where are you updating `g.site`?. How you are sure `g.site == store`, just try to print `g.site` and `response.__dict__` first line of your function,you will get some idea.

Comment: @Navaneethan  I update `g.site` in `app.before_request`

Comment: @HamidFzM then why not return a 404 *then*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abort(404)` raises an exception, it doesn't *return* the response object. But since `after_request` functions are executed after the normal view handling and outside the exception handler the `NotFound` exception raised will not be handled.

You could re-use the exception handler normally applied to views that raise an exception:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound

@app.after_request
def restricted_access(response):
    if g.site == 'store':
        return current_app.make_response(
            current_app.handle_user_exception(NotFound()))
    return response
```

The `handle_user_exception()` method does return a `response` object.

That said, if you already know `g.site`'s value in a `before_request()` handler, it'll be a lot easier to return a 404 then and there; you can safely use a `abort(404)` in a `before_request()` handler.